# Log4j rolling file size

Tags: java, log4j

I have a xml log4j configuration file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="KTS %5p [%F] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="EXCEPTION" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="C:\\exception.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} KTS %5p [%F] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="ERROR"/> 
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>                        
        </filter>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="TIMER" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="C:\\timer.log"/>       
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>     
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} KTS %5p [%F] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="INFO"/> 
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>                        
        </filter>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CA"/>
        <appender-ref ref="TIMER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="EXCEPTION"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The problem I'm having is that the file's size are passing que established file size...

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I already solved this issue and forgot to put the response here.

The problem was beacuse when I needed to restart the application, some threads were not being destroyed, locking the log file.

Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to append log4j:configuration attribute for debug.

For example.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">

<!-- something -->

</log4j:configuration>
```

Debug information is written to console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try assigning `MaxBackupIndex first and`MaxFileSize` later . If that configuration works

```
<appender name="TIMER" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="C:\\timer.log"/>       
          <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>     
          <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} KTS %5p [%F] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter"> 
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="INFO"/> 
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>                        
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>
```